# 'take' in the sense of 'cost'

Tags: verbs

Some speakers reject the following:

It took me $300 to have the car fixed.

But they accept the following:

It will take nearly $650,000 to restore this house.

The difference is that the former has an indirect object, whereas the latter does not.

Do you think 'take' in the sense of 'cost' cannot take an indirect object?

Comment: When _cost_ can imply _time_, there is at least no problem with a phrase like _it took him an hour_.

Comment: To my BrE ear, *"It took **me** $300 to have the car fixed"* sounds decidedly unnatural. I'd have no problem were it not for ***me***, but it's not easy to explain why the "ditransitive" usage doesn't work for me there. Weirdly, the problem also seems to disappear if the "cost" is *time* rather than *money*, so I'm okay with *"It took me **two days** to get the car fixed"* (perhaps the fact that I'm also strongly motivated to change ***have*** to ***get*** there is significant).

Comment: "It takes $300" and "It took $650,000" -- in both examples "took/take" are synonymous with "required/require" not "cost."

Comment: @LittleEva  Would you regard the 'take' as in 'it took me 20 days to complete the project' as synonymous with 'require/required'?

Comment: @Apollyon - yes. 20 days were required to complete the project.

Comment: I think you may have stumbled across another AmE/BrE difference. I find *"it took me $300 to have the car fixed"* entirely unobjectionable.

Comment: @Apollyon - I'm only giving you a more formal alternative to "took/taken". On the street, in the common tongue you will hear native speakers frequently use "took/taken" for cost.

Comment: I am now thinking about another potential contrast: It's common to say someone takes time to do something, but is it natural to say someone takes money to do something, as in 'He took 20 dollars to have his car washed,' meaning he spent 20 dollars for that purpose?

Comment: @PeterShor You are probably right about the Atlantic effect. It definitely sounds odd to me. We would almost certainly say *it cost me $300 to have the car fixed*.

Comment: @LittleEva *Took* and *required* provide different meanings. *It took me two days to do the job* confirms that the job did get done. *It required two days to do the job* leaves open an uncertainty as to whether it was ever done.

Comment: @WS2 - Please explain the source of the uncertainty.

Comment: @LittleEva Well, if you were working for me and said 'it required two days for me to do the job', I would not be entirely clear whether you actually did it. Your next sentence, lost for the moment because the phone is ringing, might be 'So I left it for Freda to do when she comes in next week'. But if you say 'it took two days to do it', I know that you merit the employee-of-the-month bonus, as you made a special effort to get the job finished.

Comment: Take verb past tense took require or use up (a specified amount of time).
"the jury took an hour and a half to find McPherson guilty"
synonyms: last, continue for, go on for, carry on for; More
require, call for, need, necessitate, entail, involve "the journey took six hours" 
•(of a task or situation) need or call for (a particular person or thing).
"it will take an electronics expert to dismantle it"
synonyms: require, need, necessitate, demand, call for, entail, involve 
"it would take an expert to know that"

Comment: @WS2 - the previous comment is directed toward you, I ran out of edit-time and couldn't address it. In context "took" and "required" are synonymous. You are too intelligent to be confused.

Comment: @LittleEva I did say that with *required* I would not be 'entirely' clear. I agree that it could mean one had completed the job. Indeed had it not been possible so to do, you might have said 'it would have required two days to complete', making it clear that it had not been done.

Comment: @WS2 - I'm gonna cut you some slack here, cause you're my elder. But you owe me one! :-)

Comment: @LittleEva By very many decades, I feel certain!

Comment: Oh, get a room! But seriously, "took" does not work the same as "required", in the very aspect that OP asked about; namely, you would not say "it required ME two days to do it."

Comment: Right, @Brian Hitchcock, I wasn't suggesting OP remove "took" and insert "required." I was merely trying to augment OP's translation of the vernacular, "took", which in context is being used as a synonym for "required".

Answer (score 1):

I think this is going to be a question where an authoritative answer is not going to be available. I doubt that any examples will be found in authoritative works. And looking up examples in corpuses / on the internet will probably merely give a rough indication of acceptability.

oerkelens has pointed out the comparison with the unarguably acceptable

> It took him an hour.

And

> It cost me $300.

is also acceptable.

Note that 'an hour' and '$300' here are according to some linguist neither true ('semantic') DOs nor true IOs.

But I'll throw in that

> It took me $300 to have the car fixed.

cannot be replaced by

> *It required me $300 to have the car fixed.

whereas

> It took $300 to have the car fixed.

*can* be replaced by

> It required $300 to have the car fixed.

These usages seem idiosyncratic, so we're really dependent on what people actually say.

I'd not consider 'It took me $300 to have the car fixed' unacceptable, but I'd usually use 'cost' here. The exception would probably be when I wanted to use a verb marked for great personal sacrifice; 'cost' is so common that it usually passes unmarked.

Comment: Thank you for the input.  Is the version without an indirect object like 'me', as in 'It took $300 to have the car fixed' marked or unmarked?

Comment: To my ears, it's not as natural as 'It cost $300 to have the car fixed' (Probably because it's less common in the UK; I'm mentally switching dollars to pounds though), so it's a marked usage in _some_ way. Automatically, my 'mismatch detector' starts looking for what the incongruity is. Here, I'd wonder about 'acceptability', and decide 'who's to say?'; I'd move on to look at the strange/strangish choice of 'take' and connote the violent senses across. // Now I'm checking 'connote the violent senses across'.

Comment: Isn't "took/cost" an example of imprecise, unconscious or inattentive usage of the language. I mean that's why it strains grammar.

Comment: In U.S. English, we also sometimes use expressions of the form "Fixing the car took all day." And it's not unheard of to encounter the phrasing "Fixing the car took $300."

Comment: The first, especially with a 'me', would be totally acceptable in the UK. The second would be unusual ('It cost me ...' or 'Getting the car fixed ...'). The distribution of 'take' meaning 'cost' (in financial terms) is idiosyncratic.

Answer (score 0):

I just found an example for the usage of **to take + indirect object** on the european unions web page, which of course does not mean that it is correct:

"The most significant evidence that the MIS is not operational is provided by the official auditors of OA (SOL SA - Certified auditors) in the audit reports for the years 1998, 1999 and 2000, and by **the enormous delay it took to have the accounts audited**."

see

[linguee](http://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=it%20took%20me%20%25%20to%20have) or

[europa.eu](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/LexUriServ/LexUriServ.do?uri=OJ:L:2003:132:0001:0040:EN:PDF), no. 121

Comment: the 'take' in this example is different from the one I'm concerned with, i.e. the one meaning 'cost'.

Comment: the 'take' in this example is a cost of time, not $. However, I am not sure if the currency should make a difference (€ would not make a difference at least, so why should h). Perhaps a **native speaker** could have a look on this case?

Comment: I think when native speakers talk about 'cost', they talk about it in relation to money, not time.